# RichTextBox Selected Text Position

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I need to retrieve the character position of the selected text in a RichTextBox.  I'm not sure of the best approach.  I.e.

Doe, John    123 June Ln  Houston, TX 75240

If the user highlights "123 June Ln  " I want to return 14 for the left most position and 26 for the right most position.  The highlighted text's position in the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Selection" property returns a TextSelection object which may be of use to you?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.selection.aspx

Comment: I am using the SelectedText property to get the highlighted text.  I'm at a loss at the moment on how to get the highlighted character positions in the line.

Comment: SelectedText.Start and SelectedText.End ?

Comment: I had tried those properties but was just returning the namespace.  I got this working.  int startIndex = this.richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(this.richTextBox1.Selection.Start)

Comment: Don't know why but VS tell me 'RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Selection' and no extension method 'Selection' accepting a first argument of type 'RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Any solution?